# Stopping a running process via GUI, in java

Tags: java, user-interface, testng, terminate

I have a GUI program that executes TestNG automation scripts. It's meant for users to easily configure some setting and launch the automation script that they want.

One thing I need to add is the ability to instantly stop the running TestNG process. Something like how in Eclipse, the 'Terminate' button will instantly stop whatever is running.

This is what the code that launches the TestNG tests looks like:

```
public class ScriptRunner implements Runnable {

    public void runScript() {
        Thread testRun = new Thread(this);
        testRun.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //various other things are configured for this, 
        //but they're not relevant so I left them out
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();

        //While this runs, various browser windows are open, 
        //and it could take several minutes for it all to finish
        tng.run();
    }
}
```

As per the comment, the `tng.run()` can take several minutes to complete, and it's performing several things, opening/closing browser windows, etc.

How can I just instantly terminate the process, like you would when running an application from an IDE?

EDIT:

Per the comments, I'm attempting to use a ServiceExecutor and `shutDownNow()` The code is looking like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public void runScript() {
    executorService.execute(this);
}

//this method gets called when I click the "stop" button
public void stopRun() {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //same stuff as from earlier code
}
```

Comment: System.exit(0); will terminate the JVM instantly

Comment: @OluCode Yes, but will that not also kill my GUI application too? I need a way to just kill the running TestNG object.

Comment: if its a thread, use a thread Manager like ExecutorService to handle the thread life for you and call serviceObject.shutDownNow();

Comment: Why not save the `TestNG` thread outside of the `run()` method scope and terminate it from another method?

Comment: @OluCode Thank you, but it doesn't seem to be working. The shutDownNow(); is only stopping the immediate thing the TestNG object is doing (for example, if the object has to run 10 tests each in a separate browser, calling shutDownNow() is only stopping 1 test at a time)

Comment: @CeilingGecko That sounds interesting, could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Where are you placing the threadManager?

Comment: @OluCode I've edited my question to show the new code I'm trying with the ExecutorService

Comment: 10 means your running 10 threads... is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm only running 1 thread (although the TestNG object creates many threads during its lifespan). I tried with both just 1 and with 50 (for the heck of it), and the result was the same.

Comment: yeah coz the 10 will run upto 10 threads at any one point based on the number of threads submitted using the submit method of ExecutorService

Comment: If your TestNG class is starting another thread then this will continue to run if you stop your ScriptRunner thread.

Comment: Just open it in a new Thread ;) and to stop the program kill the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently working on the executor framework. Here I have listed my problem
http://programtalk.com/java/executorservice-not-shutting-down/

Be careful if you are doing some IO operations the executor service may not shutdown immediately. If you see the below code `stopThread` is important because it tells your program that the thread has been asked to stop. And you can stop some iteration what you are doing.
I will modify your code like this:

```
public class MyClass {

private ExecutorService executorService;

private boolean stopThread = false;

public void start() {
   // gives name to threads
    BasicThreadFactory factory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
             .namingPattern("thread-%d").build();
    executorService =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                doTask();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("indexing failed", e);
            }

        }
    });
    executorService.shutdown();
}

private void doTask()  {
    logger.info("start reindexing of my objects");
    List<MyObjects> listOfMyObjects = new MyClass().getMyObjects();
    for (MyObjects myObject : listOfMyObjects) {
        if(stopThread){ // this is important to stop further indexing
            return;
        }
        DbObject dbObjects = getDataFromDB();
        // do some task
    }
}



public void stop() {
    this.stopThread = true;
    if(executorService != null){
        try {
            // wait 1 second for closing all threads
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Spawn a child JVM process using ProcessBuilder or Runtime and you will be able to terminate that process when the user requests that the script stops running.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ExecutorService to start test execution into one another thread. You can choose to have many thread in parrallel or juste one thread for all tests in sequence by choosing which executor service you need.

After that, start the execution of all tests in the same executor service instance by calling submit() method on it. You can stop the execution of all submitted runnables by calling shutdownNow() method.

It is important to use the same instance of ExecutorService, otherwise you start each test in a different thread and you will not enable to break the execution chain (or by calling shutdownNow() on all of them).

Answer (score 1):

Save all created processes and kill them when your program ends:

```
public class ProcessFactory {
  private static Set<Process> processes = new HashSet<>();
  private static boolean isRunning = true;

  public static synchronized Process createProcess(...) throws ... {
    if (!isRunning)
      throw ...
    ... // create your spawned process
    processes.add(process);
    return process;
  }

  public static synchronized void killAll() {
    isRunning = false;
    for (Process p : processes)
        p.destroy();
    processes.clear();
  }

  public static void registerShutdownHook() {
      Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
         void run() {
             killAll();
         }
      });
  }
}
```

This can be improved by adding a mechanism that removes already dead processes, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

What about this,
add a volatile static boolean and make the thread code look like...

```
if(ScriptRunner.runThread){
    //Do some stuff here
}
if(ScriptRunner.runThread){
    //Do some other stuff here
}
if(ScriptRunner.runThread){
    //Do some other stuff here
}
if(ScriptRunner.runThread){
    //Do rest of the stuff here
}
```

Now you can add a button in your main GUI that simply sets the `runThread` to false so the thread will terminate nearly instant leaving all the leftover code untouched as you press the `Stop` button.

```
public class ScriptRunner implements Runnable {

    volatile static Boolean runThread = true;

    public void runScript() {
        Thread testRun = new Thread(this);
        testRun.start();
    }

    public void terminate(){
        runThread = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //various other things are configured for this, 
        //but they're not relevant so I left them out
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();

        //While this runs, various browser windows are open, 
        //and it could take several minutes for it all to finish
        tng.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a new Thread? You have to add an `private Thread thread;` in the gui and when ever you start

```
thread = new thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       //start process here
    }
};
thread.start();
```

and to stop "terminate"

`thread.stop();`(depracted) or `thread.setDeamon(true);`

Everytime I have to stop a process by the gui I use this.

Hope I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your GUI somewhere you have something like

```
ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner();
scriptRunner.runScript();
```

When you want to stop it call

```
scriptRunner.interrupt();
```

Change the code in ScriptRunner

```
private Thread testRun;
public void runScript() {
    testRun = new Thread(this);
    testRun.start();
}

public void interrupt() {
    testRun.interrupt();
}
```